# Как задать "противоположное значение от первого ComboBoxItem" для второго ComboBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Вот разметка `ComboBox`:

```
<ComboBox Height="23.8">
    <ComboBoxItem IsSelected="True" Content="{Binding IsRight, Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}" />
    <ComboBoxItem Content="{Binding IsRight, Converter={StaticResource BoolToString}}" />
</ComboBox>
```

Для его свойства `Content` я установил привязку к свойству объекта хранящему `bool`-значение.

В моём `ComboBox`всегда будет только 2 `ComboBoxItem`.

**Проблема**

По идее, если в один `ComboBoxItem` пришло значение `true`, то у второго оно должно быть `false`. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Не могли бы вы подробнее описать, как это используется? У вас выпадающий список, который содержит два элемента IsRight и NotIsRight?

Comment: @alladuh, у меня есть выпадающий список. У него есть 2 `ComboBoxItem`. Я хочу чтобы в первый **item** в качестве значения для `Content` приходило, допустим **bool** значение `true`. А второй **item** это видел (что в первый пришло `true`) и он выводил уже `false`. И наоборот: если в первый `Item` пришло `false`, то во второй приходило `true`.

Comment: Эти `bool` считываются, благодаря `Binding` со свойства объекта, к которому привязан данный `ComboBox`.

Comment: Либо заводите коллекцию с двумя значениями и привязывайте ее к ComboBox, при этом не нужно создавать ComboBoxItem руками. Либо, раз уж начали создавать их руками – просто создайте сразу с нормальными значениями, иначе какие-то у вас полумеры

Comment: @АндрейNOP, вы немного не поняли зачем я привязал `Content` к свойству объекта... Идея в том что (сейчас немного о приложении): у меня есть список с билетами, каждый элемент списка представляет **объект c#**; у этого объекта-билета есть свойство хранящее список ответов-объектов c#; а уже у этого объекта-ответа есть свойство, которое я и привязал к `ComboBoxItem.Content`.

Comment: @zodiak1 От вашего предыдущего комментария яснее не стало, имхо

Comment: Самое простое что может быть, если я правильно понял, то сделать конвертер BoolToStringReverse, который будет менять одно значение на противоположное

Comment: @alladuh, спасибо за идею. Я её реализовал так как мне надо. Всё работает. Извините за моё "разъяснение" проблемы)